# About choosing the Lagrange multiplier correctly.

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, constraints

Suppose one wants to solve the optimization question $min_{\vec{w}} f(\vec{w})$ for some lowerbounded real valued function $f$ under the constraint $c(\vec{w}) =0$.

- Given this when and how can I choose a parameter $\lambda$ s.t solving the above question would be equivalent to trying to solve $min_{\vec{w}} \left ( f(\vec{w}) + \lambda (c(\vec{w})) \right )$ ?

---

I was looking at lecture notes on constrained non-linear optimization, http://s3.amazonaws.com/mitsloan-php/wp-faculty/sites/30/2016/12/15031343/Optimality-Conditions-for-Constrained.pdf but nothing I see here seems to answer this question.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Such a value $\lambda$ might not exist, for example when $f(x)=x$ and $c(x)=x^3$.

Comment: look at Sion's minimax theorem

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Never saw this! Any quick check you can suggest for when such a $\lambda$ might not exist? And would you know if this has a generalization for inequality constraints?

Comment: @LinAlg Actually I am not getting your point. In Sion's Theorem on both sides we have a min and a max. How would you exact use that for the current question?

Comment: The theorem can be applied if the optimization problem can be written as $\min_x \max_{\lambda \in A} f(x) + \lambda c(x)$ (for example when the constraint is $c(x) \leq 0$ you can take $A=\mathbb{R}_+$).

Comment: Here I have an equality constraint. How can this be written in the "$min_x max_\lambda$" form?

Comment: In general you cannot do that, unless you can replace the equality with an inequality, for example when $c$ is nonnegative.

Comment: The original idea in the Lagrange multipliers is to find points in which $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla c$. Those points are known as stationary points. The lagrangian is a saddle point formulation so we need additional hypothesis on $\lambda$  to treat it as a minimization/maximization problem.